# how to check if load into hive statement executed successfully or not?

Tags: hive, hdfs, impala

We have LOAD DATA Statement in hive and impala where we load data from HDFS to hive or impala table. My question is what if there is an issue in the file (may be there are less number of columns in file than that of in table or there is data mismatch for one of the columns) in such scenario whether file will get loaded or it will not load and show any error.

Comment: Did you try loading malformed file? That should give you the answer. with possible pitfalls and test it.

Comment: @Ambrish actually I havent tried that yet. Since those are client files I cannot change them. But the need to know incase this scenario occurs.Can you please help me on this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can create your own file and test it. This will give you possible cases. And when you load actual file, if anything goes wrong, you will have root cause handy with you